# Problem bash completion apt-get 12.10

Tags: command-line, apt, sudo, auto-completion

I've got an annoying problem with completion and sudo apt-get.

To give an example:

```
$ sudo apt-get in[Tab][Tab]    
in                           intel_bios_reader
includeres                   intel_disable_clock_gating
indicator-multiload          intel_dpio_read
info                         intel_dpio_write
infobrowser                  intel_error_decode
infocmp                      intel_forcewaked
infokey                      intel_gpu_abrt
infotocap                    intel_gpu_time
inimf                        intel_gpu_top
init                         intel_gtt
init-checkconf               intel_l3_parity
initctl                      intel_reg_checker
initctl2dot                  intel_reg_dumper
initex                       intel_reg_read
inkscape                     intel_reg_snapshot
inkview                      intel_reg_write
inputattach                  intel_sprite_on
insmod                       intel_stepping
install                      intel_upload_blit_large
install-docs                 intel_upload_blit_large_gtt
installfont-tl               intel_upload_blit_large_map
install-info                 intel_upload_blit_small
installkernel                interdiff
--More--
```

While is working right both with just apt-get or doing it in root:

```
$ apt-get in[Tab]stall
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for davide: 
root@brenna:~# apt-get in[Tab]stall
```

So the problem is using autocompletion after sudo? Not really, because

```
$ sudo apt-[Tab][Tab]
apt-add-repository    apt-extracttemplates  apt-key
apt-cache             apt-file              apt-mark
apt-cdrom             apt-ftparchive        apt-sortpkgs
apt-config            apt-get
```

Summing up, the problem seems to be using sudo and auto-completion for programs options together.

Any good advice for that?

Comment: Works under 12.04, might be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

It was that I had

```
complete -cf sudo
```

in my ~/.bashrc.

I don't really know what does that mean, but I'm pretty sure I added it a long time ago to make autocompletion work with sudo.

What I think is that the newer versions don't need it anymore, which is a great news! :D

So, this is solved.